# Concatenation of LPWSTR strings

Tags: c++, string, winapi, concatenation, string-concatenation

In Visual C++, I have a

```
LPWSTR mystring;
```

which is already defined somewhere else in the code.

I want to create a new LPWSTR containing:

```
"hello " + mystring + " blablabla"        (i.e. a concatenation)
```

I'm getting mad with such a simple thing (concatenation)! Thanks a lot in advance, I'm lost!

Comment: As a Unix developer, what is `LPWSTR`!?!?! Downvoter, totally inappropriate.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain It's a wide string type (AFAIK, Unix dev here too). Another brainless typedef from Win(cr)API.

Comment: `typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR, *PWSTR;`

Comment: Possibly one of the worst `typedef`s I have ever seen!

Comment: I googled this thirty times already... of course! But I'm still unable to do this simple task...

It's not as simple as it seems : because of LPWSTR, it's not very easy (for me).

Comment: @JosBas You should probably have put that in the question; [tag:c++] is particularly known for downvoting!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain What I especially hate about the Windows API (apart from the Windows API) is that they're abusing C naming conventions. What the heck is `LPWSTR` if not a preprocessor macro? Oh wait, no, it's a no-brainer typedef... Well played, Microsoft, don't even leave a small hole for obeying standards...

Comment: LPWSTR is a long pointer to a wide string, wide strings are UNICODE.

Comment: Wide strings aren't necessarily Unicode, that is a common misconception; in fact, they may not be wide enough depending on how you defined Unicode... See [Joel's Infamous Post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual C++ so I removed that tag and added WinAPI.

Comment: @ShmilTheCat : why did you loose 1 minute of your life to say to me "one minute Google on ..."      : do you really think I haven't done it yet ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The C++ way:

```
std::wstring mywstring(mystring);
std::wstring concatted_stdstr = L"hello " + mywstring + L" blah";
LPCWSTR concatted = concatted_stdstr.c_str();
```

Comment: One modification would be that `concatted` must be a `LPCWSTR`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [StringCchCatW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

Comment: That's not C++, or certainly shouldn't be.

Comment: @Captain He's already dealing with `LPWSTR`, so why not? This way, he avoids converting his desired type to a different type just to manipulate it, before converting it back again. I'd +1 if it weren't for "You need" (which implies no other solution).

Comment: @AlexChamberlain The question is about _Visual C++_.

Comment: @JBentley Changed _need to_ to _can_

Comment: @JacobSeleznev Totally irrelevant; it is not *modern* C++.

Comment: @Alex `LPWSTR` is not modern C++, so we're already outside that domain. Why therefore limit the solution to modern C++ if a practical solution exists within the problem's domain? As I said above, he ultimately needs to convert his result back to `LPWSTR` anyway.

Comment: @JBentley Because it then becomes a question of security and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::wstring mystring_w(mystring);
std::wstring out_w = L"hello " + mystring_w + L" blablabla";
LPWSTR out = const_cast<LPWSTR>(out_w.c_str());
```

'out' is a LPWSTR wrapper for 'out_w'. So as long as 'out_w' is in scope it will be good to use. Also you don't need to delete 'out' as it's is binded to 'out_w' lifecycle.

This is pretty much the same answer 'user529758' gave, but with 'chris' proposed modification.